# Regular expression in MVC using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

here is the format of my regular expression:

`@"^PR[a-zA-Z0-9-]{36}[0-9]{2}([a-zA-Z0-9-]{3}2[a-zA-Z0-9-]{12}){2,10}$"`.

There should be separate validation for each condition. So I succeeded for first three conditions using JavaScript sub-string. Just stuck for last condition i.e.

`"([a-zA-Z0-9-]{3}2[a-zA-Z0-9-]{12}){2,10}"`.

In this, I want to check every fourth character must be "2".

How do i achieve this by JavaScript?

Comment: You should be writing separate regular expressions for each condition,  breaking apart a larger regular expression won't guarantee correct results. Also, it appears that your regular expression is written in C# or some language other than JavaScript.

Comment: `(testString.match(/^(.{3}2)*$/) != null)` will confirm whether every fourth character in `testString` is `2`, but I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are asking for...

Answer (score 0):

If you have the full regex, why not just use it as a whole:

```
var regex = /^PR[a-zA-Z0-9-]{36}[0-9]{2}([a-zA-Z0-9-]{3}2[a-zA-Z0-9-]{12}){2,10}$/;
var str = "PR12345678901234567890123456789012345600AAA2BBBCCCDDDEEEaaa2bbbcccdddeee";
console.log(regex.test(str)); // true
```

But if you must really break it, you could do:

```
var regex1 = /^PR[a-zA-Z0-9-]{36}$/;
console.log(regex1.test(str.substring(0,38))); // true

var regex2 = /^[0-9]{2}$/;
console.log(regex2.test(str.substring(38,40))); // true

var regex3 = /^([a-zA-Z0-9-]{3}2[a-zA-Z0-9-]{12}){2,10}$/;
console.log(regex3.test(str.substring(40,str.length))); // true
```

See [**demo fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/qmzDf/2/).

### Edit:

To check whether every fourth character must be two, use:

```
var regexfourth = /^([a-zA-Z0-9-]{3}2)+$/;
console.log(regexfourth.test("aaa2bbb2ccc2ddd2")); // true
console.log(regexfourth.test("aaa2bbb2ccc3ddd2")); // false(notice a 3 after ccc)
```

[Demo fiddle for this here](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/qmzDf/4/) (check the bottom).

Comment: How do i check whether every fourth character must be 2 in ([a-zA-Z0-9-]{3}2[a-zA-Z0-9-]{12}){2,10}?

Comment: I added a regex example that would check every fourth. Check if this is what you need. If not, can you give more examples? Some example inputs and their expected result (false/true)...